# How to get IBM LTFS source code?

Tags: open-source

Is the IBM LTFS (Linear Tape File System) open-source?  Where can the source be downloaded from?  Is it as open-source as the HP LTFS?  IBM seems to make it difficult to find or download this source if it is available.

Comment: @user553702 if this has answered your question please don't forget to mark it as answered, thanks

Comment: It is on github since October 2017: https://github.com/LinearTapeFileSystem/ltfs

Answer (score 1):

It [appears](http://www-03.ibm.com/systems/au/storage/tape/ltfs/specifications.html) that it is Open source for Linux and Mac OS X versions and Object code only for Windows versions. Also, only the SDE version is open source. The LE one on the other hand is not, it is propriety

You need to follow [this guide:](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/ltfs/cust/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.storage.hollywood.doc/ltfs_fix_central_upgrade.html) to get to the download process.

[image: Select products]

[image: Then select the right pack]

You'll need to log in at this point to IBMs site

And if you scroll through the page you'll find multiple packs that look like this:
[image: src.rpm]

These are the source files :) You might be able to go via [this link](http://www-933.ibm.com/support/fixcentral/swg/downloadFixes?parent=Tape%20drivers%20and%20software&product=ibm/Storage_Tape/LTFS%20Library%20Edition%20%28LE%29&release=All&platform=All&function=fixId&fixids=Linear_Tape_File_System_LE_Linux&includeRequisites=1&includeSupersedes=0&downloadMethod=http)

Comment: Thanks @ohope5 I didn't realise that was the case

Comment: Yeah, it looks like I just needed to make an IBM account.  Is open-source technically still considered to be both "gratis" and "libre" if you have to make an account on the website?

Comment: @user553702 sure, why not? The account is free and you can set it up with fake information if your fussed. I did.